# Perl - Is it good practice to use the empty string as false?

Tags: perl, string

Is it safe/good practice in Perl to use an empty string as false in boolean comparisons?

ex:

```
my $s = '';

if($s) {
 print 'true';
} else {
 print 'false';
}
```

or would the length function be a better way to go:

```
my $s = '';

if(length($s) > 0) {
 print 'true';
} else {
 print 'false';
}
```

Comment: Vivin - not sure what you mean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When testing for true/false in an expression, you should think carefully about what you actually want to test.

If you have a string and you need to check if it has any value at all, then test for that:

```
if (defined $string) { ... }
```

If you are passing back a "boolean" value from a function, or testing the result of some internal operation, then perform a boolean check:

```
if ($value) { ... }
```

In Perl, "truth" depends on the manner in which it is evaluated.  If you simply say `if ($value)`, then the only *string* values that evaluate to false are the empty string `''`, and a literal zero `'0'`.  (Also, any undefined value is false, so if `$value` has never been assigned, that would be false too.)

There are other values which may evaluate to false in a *numerical* context, for example `0E0`, `0.0000`, and the string `'0 but true'`.  So the question "what is truth" really depends on the context, which you the programmer need to be aware of.

Internally, Perl uses `''` for false and `1` for truth (for example as the result of any boolean expression such as `!$value`).  A common technique for "canonicalizing" any value into one of these two values is `!!$value` -- it inverts a value twice, giving you either `''` or `1`.

Comment: its worth also mentioning the various casting operators are useful when checking for truth.  in particular, the double negation `!!` will always convert a value into a valid boolean

Comment: @Eric: I think you added that comment right while I was adding my last sentence :D

Answer (score 6):

A string can have length but still be false -- specifically, the string `'0'` (details: [Perl Truth and Falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood)). At least in the general case, `length` does not provide a robust test for truth.

```
my $s = '0';

print "'0' is false.\n"      unless $s;
print "But it has length.\n" if length $s;
```

Typically, you should use the test the characteristic that expresses what you really care about. For example, if you ask a user to enter his favorite age, `'0'` is a false but valid response: "My first year of life was great, and then everything went to hell."